# Invalid syntax python problem (if statement many actions)

Tags: if-statement, syntax-error, action

I am encountering a problem on my python code. I'm trying to increment and decrement two values after an if statement. However, this couldn't be achieved (Error: invalid syntax). Knowing that when I increment only a single value (e.g. A_p), it works well. Does the error come from the and operator? Is there a way to perform multiple actions after an if statement?

Thank you.

Omer

```
k1 = 0.2
k2 = 0.2 
Delta_t = 2


A_p = 4
B_p = 3


list_nm = [0.800, 0.801, 0.752, 0.661, 0.169, 0.956, 0.949, 0.003, 0.201, 0.291, 0.615, 0.131, 0.241, 0.685, 0.116, 0.241, 0.849]

for i in range(7):
    if list_nm[i] < (A_p/7):
        print("Particle A was choosen")
        if list_nm[i] < k1*Delta_t:
            A_p -= 1 and B_p += 1
        else:
            A_p = A_p and B_p = B_p
    elif list_nm[i] < (B_p/7):
        print("Particle B was choosen")
        if list_nm[i] < k2*Delta_t:
            A_p +=1 and B_p -=1
        else:
            A_p = A_p and B_p = B_p
    else:
        print("No choice was made")
        A_p = A_p and B_p = B_p
print(B_p)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A_p -= 1 and B_p += 1
```

is not valid Python, `and` is a specific keyword used for combining booleans, such as:

```
if a > 3 and a < 7:
    pass
```

What you're after instead is two separate statements:

```
A_p -= 1
B_p += 1
```

or, if you *must* have it on a single line (and I'd question *why* you think this is necessary), one of the following, depending on what you prefer:

```
A_p -= 1 ; B_p += 1
(A_p, B_p) = (A_p - 1, B_p + 1)
```

---

In addition, the line:

```
A_p = A_p and B_p = B_p
```

even when you split it into two statements, is effectively doing nothing. You may as well remove it totally, along with the `else:` line preceding it if that's the only thing in the `else` block.

In other words, start with something this:

```
(k1, k2, Delta_t) = (0.2, 0.2, 2)
(A_p, B_p) = (4, 3)

list_nm = [0.800, 0.801, 0.752, 0.661, 0.169, 0.956, 0.949, 0.003, 0.201, 0.291, 0.615, 0.131, 0.241, 0.685, 0.116, 0.241, 0.849]

for i in range(7):
    if list_nm[i] < (A_p / 7):
        print("Particle A was choosen")
        if list_nm[i] < k1 * Delta_t:
            A_p -= 1
            B_p += 1
    elif list_nm[i] < (B_p / 7):
        print("Particle B was choosen")
        if list_nm[i] < k2 * Delta_t:
            A_p += 1
            B_p -= 1
    else:
        print("No choice was made")
print(B_p)
```